# Map List by Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, list, return-value

I have a generic `List<Package>` called `packages`.

I invoke for each item the method `VersionControlGetStatus()` from `Package` class. The method returns an integer value.

```
 List<EA.Package> list = packages.ForEach(p => p.VersionControlGetStatus());
```

I would like to map the items in the list according to the returned value from the method to create several `List<Package>` according the returned values.

How should I update the code above?

**EDIT:**

For example I have 3 items in `packages` list: `a`, `b`, `c`.

When I invoke the method for each item, the returned value for `a` and `b` is 1.
The returned value for `c` is 8.

**Desired result:**

Two new `List<Package>`s; the first contains `a` and `b`, the second contains `c`.

Comment: What do you mean by map the items? do you want to create a map of Item and the returned value or you want to sort the list of items by returned value?

Comment: Are you talking about grouping the lists by the returned value so you have one list of things that return 0, another list of things that return 1, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `GroupBy()` as Typist suggested, but work with the groupings directly. They contain a list of packages and a Key:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,Package>> groups = packages.GroupBy(p => p.VersionControlGetStatus()).OrderBy(g => g.Key);

foreach(IGrouping<int,Package> g in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} | Count: {1}", g.Key, g.Count());

    Package first = g.First();

    Console.WriteLine("First package in group: " + first.ToString());
}
```

And if you want packages with a certain status:

```
List<Package> value1Packages = groups.Single(g => g.Key == 1).ToList();
```

---

**Edit**: included explicit types instead of var for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Use Linq `GroupBy` clause

```
var listOfPackages = packages.GroupBy(p => p.VersionControlGetStatus())
                             .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

`listOfPackages` is an `IEnumerable<List<package>>`

This will give you 2 lists according to your example. And you can access the package from the 2 returned lists like below -

```
foreach(var packageList in listOfPackages) {
    foreach(var pack in packageList ) {
        // work with your pacakge
    }        
}
```

Comment: how can I detect the returned value of each list?

Comment: `packageList` should have a `Key` property.

Comment: @Typist, Thanks for the update. I would like to know what is the returned  value that each new list represent: Is it 1 or 8 for example.

Comment: @Jasd, What do you mean?

Comment: The return value of the calls to `p.VersionControlGetStatus()` are stored in `packageList.Key`

Comment: Jasd: Does the `Select` not actually mean that `listOfPackages` won't have a `Key` any more?

Comment: @Chris, you are right, I overlooked that the keys got lost when converting the groups to lists with the select statement (`.Select(g => g.ToList())`)

Comment: lists will contain the actual packages. first list = (a,b) and second list = (c)

Comment: @Typist, I would like to get the value returned for (a,b) and the value returned for (c).

Comment: ok. do you mean - you want the list of int values instead of list of packages, right?

Comment: @Typist, Actually, no. I would like to iterate on the lists that I get from the linq expression you post, then to print the list name (returned value) and the items in it.

Comment: That you can do in the for loops. You have access to the package where you can print the name from the package object and you can execute the VersionControlGetStatus() on the package.

Comment: @Typist, can you please guide me how to get one list of all elements in the original list that return the number 7 for example.

Comment: @Typist: Why not just leave out the select at the end and then you have an `IGrouping` with the Key property on it. No point running `VersionControlGetStatus` again - instead just don't throw away that information.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks, can you post a sample using the `IGrouping` keyword?

Comment: @user3165438: I've done an answer using grouping more directly (similar to EagleBeak's) and also added in some info about ToLookup in case you want to get the sublists by status rather than just looping through all the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try code based on the following:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, EA.Package>> groupedPackages = packages.GroupBy(p => p.VersionControlGetStatus());

foreach (IGrouping<int, EA.Package> packageGroup in groupedPackages)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + packageGroup.Key.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Packages:");
    foreach (EA.Package package in packageGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(package.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The first line creates an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<>>`. The `IGrouping` is basically an `IEnumerable` that has the key used to group on it. WE can thus loop over our groupedPackages to get a `packageGroup` that has a key and do with that what we want. We then can loop over that `packageGroup` as we would any other enumerable and do what we want.

You can also do things like create a lookup from the original list to allow you to easily access a specific status with something like:

```
 Lookup<int, EA.Package> packageLookup = packages.ToLookup(p=>p.VersionControlGetStatus());
 IEnumerable<EA.Package> status0Packages = packageLookup[0];
```

Which is better for you depends on how you are going to use them.

Note: all code has been written directly into this editor window and is untested so may contain minor syntax errors or typos.